# How to Compare $options.data()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
if (this.filter !== this.$options.data().filter){
    console.log('current filter have same value like when first time created')
}
```

this if always return false although they are have same value, because this.filter return Observer. How to compare them properly?

[image]

Comment: Referencing your `objects`'s, why not just compare the `value` of `brand`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)